# ReactJS Jvectormap: calling setstate on onRegionClick causes country to not be filled

Tags: reactjs, jvectormap

My onregionclick function uses another function:

`onRegionClick={handleClick}`

In handleclick, I am calling state like so:

```
const handleClick = (e, countryCode) => {
  setGuesses(guesses + 1);
}
```

however, this causes the country to not fill, for no particular reason.

if i remove the setstate call and add anything else, the country fills normally.